# How to convert the CTEs to temporary tables or subqueries. PostgreSQL to Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

```
WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT '2020-03-01'::date AS start_date, '2020-04-01'::date AS end_date
),
start_accounts AS
(
SELECT account_id, SUM(mrr) AS total_mrr
FROM subscription s INNER JOIN date_range d ON
s.start_date<= d.start_date
AND (s.end_date>d.start_date or s.end_date is null)
GROUP BY account_id
),
end_accounts AS
(
SELECT account_id, SUM(mrr) AS total_mrr
FROM subscription s INNER JOIN date_range d ON
s.start_date<= d.end_date
AND (s.end_date>d.end_date or s.end_date is null)
GROUP BY account_id
),
retained_accounts AS
(
SELECT s.account_id, SUM(e.total_mrr) AS total_mrr
FROM start_accounts s
INNER JOIN end_accounts e ON s.account_id=e.account_id
GROUP BY s.account_id
),
start_mrr AS (
SELECT SUM (start_accounts.total_mrr) AS start_mrr
FROM start_accounts
),
retain_mrr AS (
SELECT SUM(retained_accounts.total_mrr) AS retain_mrr
FROM retained_accounts
)
SELECT
retain_mrr /start_mrr AS net_mrr_retention_rate,
1.0 - retain_mrr /start_mrr AS net_mrr_churn_rate,
start_mrr,
retain_mrr
FROM start_mrr, retain_mrr
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Both Postgres and SQL Server support CTEs.

Comment: Seems, only the first CTE needs to be amended SELECT cast('2020-03-01' as date) AS start_date, cast('2020-04-01' as date) AS end_date. All others can be used "as it is"

Comment: The only thing I see in this query that isn't supported in SQL Server is this syntax `'2020-03-01'::date` which I assume sis PostgreSql's way to saying that this is a date data type. If my assumption is correct, the SQL Server's equivalent is `CAST('2020-03-01' AS date)`

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are actually asking. Do you need to fix a problem in a Postgres query? Do you need to write a query that works without change in Postgres and SQL Server? Do you need to migrate a Postgres query to SQL Server?

Comment: This query is for Postgres. I want to create on Microsoft SQL.

Comment: Your code does not support multiple periods, so why encourage the idea using that first CTE (which is syntactically invalid). Just replace it with 2 scalar variables. The use of those dates looks highly suspicious in different ways but that is a different problem. If you fix the syntax errors in the first CTE it seems your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

`Expression:targettype` casting is postgresql specific syntax for type casting. But, you have to use ANSI syntax `CAST(Expression AS targettype)` or SQL Server specific `CONVERT(targettype,Expression)` to make it work in SQL Server.

you need to use separate CAST in the first CTE for it to work in SQL Server.

From:

```sql
WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT '2020-03-01'::date AS start_date, '2020-04-01'::date AS end_date
)
```

To:

```sql
WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT CAST('2020-03-01' as date) AS start_date, cast('2020-04-01' AS date) AS end_date
)

or

WITH
date_range AS (
SELECT CONVERT(date,'2020-03-01') AS start_date, CONVERT(DATE,'2020-04-01') AS end_date
)
```